# Deleting cookies in scrapy Request

Tags: cookies, scrapy, session-variables

I am using scrapy + selenium, since the website I am scrapping needs javascript for authentication. I login with selenium and pass the cookies to the following request.

```
def login(self, response):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("http://www.site.com/login")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='myname']").send_keys(settings['USERNAME'])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='mypwd']").send_keys(settings['PASSWORD'])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='Logon']").click()
    self.driver = driver
    return Request(url=driver.current_url, cookies=self.driver.get_cookies(), callback=self.after_login, dont_filter=True)
```

So far so good, since cookies are sticky all the following requests work perfectly well. My scrapping is quite long, so at some point cookies expire, so I need to relogin. At this point I am passing a new Request with callback to login function. Here it fails since new cookies are merged with old ones. Is there a way to reset cookies?

**ANSWER**

@Drewness in his answer suggested to use `dont_merge_cookies` attribute in meta dictionary. It didn't work due to the following reason. According to the [source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/bf6ef29182b2194ea0e40f28e37da60cbbcfb48d/scrapy/contrib/downloadermiddleware/cookies.py#L24-25), the following Request:

```
Request(url=driver.current_url, cookies=self.driver.get_cookies(), callback=self.after_login, meta={'dont_merge_cookies' : True}, dont_filter=True)
```

should do nothing with cookies you pass to him.

In my solution I decided to skip `dont_merge_cookies` attribute and simply reset the response headers just before creating the request:

```
response.headers = {}
return Request(url=driver.current_url, cookies=self.driver.get_cookies(), callback=self.after_login, dont_filter=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html):

> When some site returns cookies (in a response) those are stored in the
>   cookies for that domain and will be sent again in future requests.
>   That’s the typical behaviour of any regular web browser. However, if,
>   for some reason, you want to avoid merging with existing cookies you
>   can instruct Scrapy to do so.

Like so:

```
request_with_cookies = Request(url="http://www.example.com",
                               cookies={'currency': 'USD', 'country': 'UY'},
                               meta={'dont_merge_cookies': True})
```

`dont_merge_cookies` being the key here of course.

Comment: Hi @Drewness, I have edited the original post according to your suggestion. Am I missing smthg?